# Remote connection that i cannot disconnect from, local network i think

Tags: networking, remote-connection

```
10:e7:c6:51:1c:16
WPA2-PSK-CCMP
RSN-PSK-CCMP
Wi-Fi standard: 11n, bandwidth: 20MHz 11e(O) 11k(X) 11v(X) 11r(X ) 11w(X)
```

[image]

Please help me to know what this connection is and how to disconnect and block it.

[image]

Comment: Since you are not connected to this Wi-Fi network, there is nothing to disconnect from. If you don't want to see nearby networks this way, turn off Wi-Fi developer options.

Comment: it is connected to my phone at times and its an Ehpermal  port connection

Comment: 10:e7:c6:51:1c:16[WPA2-PSK-CCMP] [RSN-PSK-CCMP]Wi-Fi standard: 11n, bandwidth: 20MHz 11e(O) 11k(X) 11v(X) 11r(X ) 11w(X)

Comment: It is not connected to your phone, your phone may (attempt to) connect to it though. That is an important distinction. It may be your phone is just hunting for networks to connect to & attempts to connect to that one, it makes the initial connection before being denied & that is what you are seeing.